# 2 versions (sandboxed or not), 1 app - Optimum approach

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

OK, this is a conceptual question actually.

I'm currently building an OSX app which I'm going to release both **in** the App Store and on my website - given that the App Store itself, with the Sandbox, implies too many restrictions in the very functionality of the app.

**The thing is:**

- The code is actually the same
- The sandboxed app will have the extra *Sandbox entitlements*
- The sandboxed app should have *a few capabilities disabled* (actually removed)

What's the best approach, so that I do not end up maintaining 2 separate code bases?

---

*P.S. I know it must have something to do with Target, Schemes, etc - but, having had a look at the documentation, it seems rather confusing and I'm still not sure it's what I'm trying to achieve. Which one is the way to go? Any pointers/references?*

Comment: So you're not calling the methods in the non-MAS app but *the code is still in there* - Sure it'll pass the review process where they poke around in your binaries for stuff not allowed in MAS apps?

Comment: @Jay Well, I'm pretty sure about it. In fact, it has happened to me numerous times - and I'm selling over 40 apps in MAS. :-)